# Sending random data to API using Python Flask

Tags: python, api, flask

I am trying to send random data to API using python flask with intervals of 1 second. But it only shows the last array of data. I am using the following code:

```
import time
import random
import datetime
from flask import Flask

mylist = []
ct = datetime.datetime.now()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def index():
    mylist = []
    ct = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range(0, 61):
        x = random.randint(1, 100)
        mylist.append(x)

        if len(mylist) == 11:
            right_in_left_out = mylist.pop(0)
        else:
            right_in_left_out = None

        time.sleep(1)
        print(mylist)
    return mylist

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

OUTPUT:

WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
* Debugger PIN: 516-689-025

```
[50]
[50, 61]
[50, 61, 47]
[50, 61, 47, 63]
[50, 61, 47, 63, 24]
[50, 61, 47, 63, 24, 92]
[50, 61, 47, 63, 24, 92, 18]
[50, 61, 47, 63, 24, 92, 18, 75]
[50, 61, 47, 63, 24, 92, 18, 75, 95]
[50, 61, 47, 63, 24, 92, 18, 75, 95, 4]
[61, 47, 63, 24, 92, 18, 75, 95, 4, 40]
[47, 63, 24, 92, 18, 75, 95, 4, 40, 88]
[63, 24, 92, 18, 75, 95, 4, 40, 88, 39]
[24, 92, 18, 75, 95, 4, 40, 88, 39, 47]
[92, 18, 75, 95, 4, 40, 88, 39, 47, 58]
[18, 75, 95, 4, 40, 88, 39, 47, 58, 82]
[75, 95, 4, 40, 88, 39, 47, 58, 82, 88]
[95, 4, 40, 88, 39, 47, 58, 82, 88, 7]
[4, 40, 88, 39, 47, 58, 82, 88, 7, 90]
[40, 88, 39, 47, 58, 82, 88, 7, 90, 65]
[88, 39, 47, 58, 82, 88, 7, 90, 65, 93]
[39, 47, 58, 82, 88, 7, 90, 65, 93, 9]
[47, 58, 82, 88, 7, 90, 65, 93, 9, 55]
[58, 82, 88, 7, 90, 65, 93, 9, 55, 48]
[82, 88, 7, 90, 65, 93, 9, 55, 48, 83]
[88, 7, 90, 65, 93, 9, 55, 48, 83, 96]
[7, 90, 65, 93, 9, 55, 48, 83, 96, 63]
[90, 65, 93, 9, 55, 48, 83, 96, 63, 8]
[65, 93, 9, 55, 48, 83, 96, 63, 8, 43]
[93, 9, 55, 48, 83, 96, 63, 8, 43, 49]
[9, 55, 48, 83, 96, 63, 8, 43, 49, 95]
[55, 48, 83, 96, 63, 8, 43, 49, 95, 92]
[48, 83, 96, 63, 8, 43, 49, 95, 92, 43]
[83, 96, 63, 8, 43, 49, 95, 92, 43, 57]
[96, 63, 8, 43, 49, 95, 92, 43, 57, 91]
[63, 8, 43, 49, 95, 92, 43, 57, 91, 61]
[8, 43, 49, 95, 92, 43, 57, 91, 61, 27]
[43, 49, 95, 92, 43, 57, 91, 61, 27, 66]
[49, 95, 92, 43, 57, 91, 61, 27, 66, 70]
[95, 92, 43, 57, 91, 61, 27, 66, 70, 4]
[92, 43, 57, 91, 61, 27, 66, 70, 4, 34]
[43, 57, 91, 61, 27, 66, 70, 4, 34, 11]
[57, 91, 61, 27, 66, 70, 4, 34, 11, 95]
[91, 61, 27, 66, 70, 4, 34, 11, 95, 71]
[61, 27, 66, 70, 4, 34, 11, 95, 71, 35]
[27, 66, 70, 4, 34, 11, 95, 71, 35, 4]
[66, 70, 4, 34, 11, 95, 71, 35, 4, 98]
[70, 4, 34, 11, 95, 71, 35, 4, 98, 18]
[4, 34, 11, 95, 71, 35, 4, 98, 18, 81]
[34, 11, 95, 71, 35, 4, 98, 18, 81, 87]
[11, 95, 71, 35, 4, 98, 18, 81, 87, 84]
[95, 71, 35, 4, 98, 18, 81, 87, 84, 37]
[71, 35, 4, 98, 18, 81, 87, 84, 37, 63]
[35, 4, 98, 18, 81, 87, 84, 37, 63, 42]
[4, 98, 18, 81, 87, 84, 37, 63, 42, 18]
[98, 18, 81, 87, 84, 37, 63, 42, 18, 79]
[18, 81, 87, 84, 37, 63, 42, 18, 79, 28]
[81, 87, 84, 37, 63, 42, 18, 79, 28, 12]
[87, 84, 37, 63, 42, 18, 79, 28, 12, 36]
[84, 37, 63, 42, 18, 79, 28, 12, 36, 23]
[37, 63, 42, 18, 79, 28, 12, 36, 23, 49]
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Sep/2022 12:55:46] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

OUTPUT AT API:

[image]

I am looking to send data the same way as it is being displayed in the IDE with 1 sec intervals.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here

```
if len(mylist) == 11:
        right_in_left_out = mylist.pop(0)
```

Once this code executes for the first time, your list size is back to 10 , further iterations everytime it becomes 11 and then back to 10!

Comment: I know that. But the API only shows the last line of the output. I want it to show all the output arrays. The output is correct but the output at API is not

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning a list, and that is logical. If you want to return all the lists like the ones you displayed, you have to store them in a list of lists.
I mean by that:

```
    all_lists = []
    mylist = []
    ct = datetime.datetime.now()
    for i in range(0, 61):
        x = random.randint(1, 100)
        mylist.append(x)

        if len(mylist) == 11:
            mylist.pop(0)

        time.sleep(1)
        all_lists.append(mylist)
        print(mylist)
    return all_lists
```

There is also no need to use `right_in_left_out` variable in your code.

Comment: It didnt work. It just displayed the same last list 60 times

Comment: @MJay I updated my code, can you try it now?